# Keep GET-Values saved

Tags: javascript, location-href

I have function like this:

```
 function SetPageShow (obj)
    {
        window.location.href="?CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA="+obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
    }
```

and it works fine until I have a page with another GET-values like

```
http://protectneu/main.php?site=mitarb&liz=260
```

. then when I call the function SetPageShow, the URL will be

```
http://protectneu/main.php?CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA=25
```

and the other values(mitarb and liz) are getting lost. Is there a way to keep them saved and just add the new paramethers. The result that I need is:

```
http://protectneu/main.php?site=mitarb&liz=260&CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA=25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the PHP side you need to strip out the parameters that you would send via JavaScript, then build a string with the other parameters, like so:

```
<?php
$params = $_GET;
unset($params['CMD']);
unset($params['PARA']);

?>
<script>
function SetPageShow(obj)
{
    var params = '<?php echo http_build_query($params); ?>';

    window.location.href = '?' + (params ? params + '&' : '') + "CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA=" + encodeURIComponent(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Btw, I've also added `encodeURIComponent()` in JavaScript to perform proper escaping of the selected value.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (window.location.search)  
  return window.location.href + "&CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA="+obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;  
else 
  return window.location.href + "?CMD=PAGEROWS&PARA="+obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: If the next page has the same JavaScript in it, it will send two sets of `CMD` and `PARA` though; the last values could prevail (in PHP) but ASP will turn them into an array for instance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using PHP's [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) if you want to retain information like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = $bar;
?>
```

Then you can refer to this information on other pages by calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the page.

```
<?php
session_start();
$bar = $_SESSION['foo'];
?>
```